# Add Parameters to DB Cluster parameter group in AWS Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have written a CloudFormation template that creates a DBClusterParameterGroup and I am trying to add parameters to it. Each time the stack tries to create it gives error messages for Invalid / Unsupported DB Parameter for both ParameterName and ParameterValue. This is the way the cli command for adding parameters references those 2 values. How do I pass these add these two values into the DB Cluster Parameter group if those Parameter names are not recognized in CloudFormation

```
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "Description": "parameter group",
                "Family": "aurora5.6",
                "Parameters": {
                    "ParameterName": "aws_default_lambda_role",
                    "ParameterValue": "arn:aws:iam::..."
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```json
{
    "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup",
    "Properties": {
        "Description": "parameter group",
        "Family": "aurora5.6",
        "Parameters": {
            "ParameterName": "aws_default_lambda_role",
            "ParameterValue": "arn:aws:iam::..."
        }
    }
}
```

should be changed to

```json
{
    "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup",
    "Properties": {
        "Description": "parameter group",
        "Family": "aurora5.6",
        "Parameters": {
            "aws_default_lambda_role": "arn:aws:iam::...",
            ... add other parameters in format "name": "value"
        }
    }
}
```

**References:**

Examples section for `AWS::RDS::DBClusterParameterGroup`:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbclusterparametergroup.html#aws-resource-rds-dbclusterparametergroup--examples